Personalize contour plot using Plots and gr backend in Julia
I have julia Pluto notebook with a contour plot done using Plots and gr(). I want to customize the contour line labels and the legend on the right to be in exponential format with two significant digits. How can I do that? Also, how can I modify the font of said labels? Thanks!
Example:
x_values = range(0.4, 0.75, length=n_values); 
T_values = range(10.0, 30.0, length=n_values);
contour(x_values, T_values, G_t, clabels=true, clabelsize=30, fill = true, color=:turbo, xlabel="x [-]", ylabel="T0 [-]")

Output:

I tried to use several arguments for formatting the clabel but none worked

One way is to work with levels
contour(x_values, T_values, G_t, 
        clabels=true, 
        clabelsize=30, 
        fill = true, 
        color=:turbo, 
        xlabel="x [-]", 
        ylabel="T0 [-]", 
        levels=round.(range(minimum(G_t), maximum(G_t), length=15), sigdigits=3))

Changing the global font works with fontfamily, e.g. ..., fontfamily="Courier"). I am not aware of any attribute that just changes the clab's font.

thank you i was able to format the contour line labels. I now have to find a way to edit the cbar labels. I'm thinking of switching to Makie, doing this kind of plots there seems to be more straightforawrd
